# Slider with async function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, slider

Hello this is my code and jsfiddle

```
<div id="section-2" class="section">
    <div class="fullContentWrap">
      <!-- client_logos_row -->
      <div class="flexRow toLeft" style="left: 0%;">
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flexRow toLeft" style="left: 0%;">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- flexRow toLeft -->
    </div>
    <!-- fullContentWrap -->
  </div>

$(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("interval doc ready");
        var  currToLeft = $('.toLeft').first();
        currToLeft.addClass("toLeftActive");
       var myInt = setInterval(intFunc,3000);
       console.log('myInt set');
       function intFunc() {
         console.log('intFunc !');
         currToLeft.animate({left: '-101%'}, "slow",function () {
           $(this).removeClass("toLeftActive");
           $(this).css("left",'0%');
           currToLeft = $(this).next();
           if (currToLeft.length === 0) {
             currToLeft = $('.toLeft').first();
           }
           currToLeft.addClass('toLeftActive');
         });
       }
       // intFunc
    });
   //  document ready




 .box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .flexRow {
    display: flex;
  }
  .toLeft{
    display: none;
    left: 100%;
  }
  .toLeftActive {
    display: flex !important;
  }
  .flexRow:nth-child(1) .box:nth-child(1) {
    background: blue;
  }
  .flexRow:nth-child(1) .box:nth-child(2) {
    background: red;
  }
  .flexRow:nth-child(1) .box:nth-child(3) {
    background: orange;
  }
  .flexRow:nth-child(2) .box:nth-child(1) {
    background: aqua;
  }
  .flexRow:nth-child(2) .box:nth-child(2) {
    background: green;
  }
  .flexRow:nth-child(2) .box:nth-child(3) {
    background: brown;
  }
  div#section-2 {
      position: relative;
  }

  div#section-2>.fullContentWrap {
      position: inherit;
  }

  div#section-2>.fullContentWrap>.flexRow {
      position: inherit;
      justify-content: center;
  }

  div#section-2>.fullContentWrap>.flexRow>div {
      position: inherit;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2918ztze/
As you can guess I am making a slider. The first block should go out of the screen to the left and the other one should come from right to left:0 ***meanwhile***.
I am not sure how this meanwhile part should be done, probably with some async coding, but how do I do it?

Comment: cannot see your code neither your fiddle as mentioned in the first line?

Comment: Edited your question a bit to make the script visible. Please accept the change

Comment: As I understand, your question is about making slide1 slideout while slide 2 slides in. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal yes you are right

Comment: Yet another slider... -_-